# Devise Admin in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Having problems with the Admin log in with devise as I can't remember the password and email. Any suggestions on how to fix this to gain access?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can just manually set the password via the Rails console:

```
u = User.first
u.password = u.password_confirmation = 'new password'
u.save
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can I change the first user to be the admin?

Comment: This works on any user, so long as you can fetch it, so either `User.find(...)` or `User.find_by(...)` depending on how you want to get it.

Comment: I have changed the admin to true on the first user but it still doesn't recognise the log in details. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's another issue, and another question.